# How do you get an NFT's transaction history?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, nft

Can you do this in a contract like get the last or first transfer date? Or do I need to make my own centralized database that keeps track of this stuff?

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve NFT history using the OpenSea API. This is what metamask uses for getting information for its NFT wallet on mobile devices. In particular you might be interest in the `events` api found [here](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-asset-events)